# Firebase data binding doesnt load on first time

Tags: javascript, angularjs, data-binding, firebase

I am trying to simply display a string of text when I load it from firebase. It is not display the data I load on the first try, if i change views it does... Everything is wired up correctly as I can display a dummy string of text. I have it properly loggin in the console but its not binding to the template. Im not sure what Im doing wrong, i searched everyweher. Thanks

```
//js controller
var firebaseRef = new Firebase("https://myGreatApp.firebaseio.com/1")     
  firebaseRef.once("value", function(snapshot) {
  var itemSnap = snapshot.val();
  $scope.itemName = itemSnap.name   
  console.log('loaded: ' + $scope.itemName) //return successful
})
$scope.TestString = "Hello World!!" //this binds


//html
{{TestString}}
{{itemName}} <!-- Doesnt work -->
```

Comment: Initialize $scope.itemName first, just use $scope.itemName = "Whatever"; then yes, just how you define $scope.TestString

Comment: @MiguelLattuada, i tried doing that. I tried both `$scope.itemName;` and `$scope.itemName =""` niether worked.

Comment: No way, what if you just $scope.$apply() after assign $scope.itemName

Comment: Otherwise you can use AngularFire, https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/quickstart.html

Comment: i made wrapped the ref in a firebase object and made sure it was loaded. that did the strick. Thanks for your help, here it is for anyone else `var link = $firebaseObject(firebaseRef);
    link.$loaded().then(function(){ do stuff..`